# How to resolve the "Expected a type" error in ios

Tags: ios

Am new to development.I got an error regarding the "Expected a Type" error.In two classes of my application,i declared the method in one class and in another class i used that method with the help of @protocol method.How to resolve it.Two classes DayButton.h and DDCalenderView.h
In `DayButton.h`, i declared as

```
 @protocol DayButtonDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)dayButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

And in `DDCalenderView.h`,i wrote as

```
@protocol DDCalenderViewDelegate<NSObject>
-(void)dayButtonPressed:(DayButton *)button;
```

Getting an exception near void method in `DDCalenderView.h`

Comment: Can you post some snippet of code here?

Comment: ok i will edit the question.give me few minutes

Comment: What action you are going to perform with these classes

Comment: This is about the calender logic.In DayButton.h,i declared and in DDCalenderView.m,i wrote the relevant logic for that to be worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION: Move the import from the implementation to the header file.
 I think that there were some imports in the implementation file that were not in the header file.Make sure that you have the correct import.  It’s one of those little bugs/mistakes that make you shake your head… at yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It worked finally.I imported the classes in .m file but not in .h file

Answer (score 2):

In DDCalenderView.h you should type `@class DayButton;` above `@protocol DDCalenderViewDelegate<NSObject>`. This will tell the compiler that DayButton is a class (that is declared somewhere else).

You can also add `#import "DayButton.h"` to the top of DDCalenderView.h.